# Why do I use extern crate for alloc instead of `use std::alloc`?

Tags: arbitrum, rust, stylus

I'm making a simple storage contract in [stylus](https://arbitrum.io/stylus), but I'm confused as to why I can't import `alloc` like I can other imports.

I have two kinds of imports

```rust
// the extern
extern crate alloc;

// The classic use import
use stylus_sdk::{
    alloy_primitives::U256,
    prelude::{entrypoint, external, sol_storage},
};
```

But the following doesn't compile for me:

```
use std::alloc
```

Because it gives me errors with `entrypoint`

```rust
sol_storage! {
    #[entrypoint]
    pub struct SimpleStorage {
        uint256 my_favorite_number;
    }
}
```

```bash
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `vec` in `alloc`
  --> src/main.rs:20:5
   |
20 |     #[entrypoint]
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ could not find `vec` in `alloc`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Edition 2015` of Rust, `extern crate` was used to import crates. However, [that is no longer necessary](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/path-changes.html#no-more-extern-crate). The "sysroot" crates are an [exception](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/path-changes.html#an-exception) though, and `alloc` is one of them. That is why you need to import it with an `extern crate` statement.

---

Why do you need to import `alloc` with `stylus-sdk`? Well, the nature of the Stylus' WASM VM makes it a very constrained environment for running programs, which means that we must reduce binary size as much as possible. In this environment, it is useful to use [`no_std`](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/9eyc21/noob_what_exactly_is_no_std_and_why_is_it_so/).

The authors of `stylus-sdk` have predicted this beforehand and, thus, use `alloc` directly without importing `std`. This enables users to use both `std` and `no_std` as they see fit and falls back to `no_std`, which should be the common case.

---

[`std::vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/index.html) is the place where `Vec` and its associated structs live.

To use `Vec` in a `no_std` environment, you'd use `alloc::vec::Vec`.

Answer (score 0):

> Items in the alloc crate are usually accessed via re-exports in the std crate. If you are working with a no_std crate that supports allocation, then you may need to explicitly import alloc.

so just use the `std::vec` or you need `extern crate alloc;`

[excption in No more extern crate](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/path-changes.html#an-exception)

Comment: I don't follow. What is `std::vec`?